# Login forms - buggy online examples

Tags: php, authentication

I took the majority of this code from an online example; looking over the code, everything seemed to be in order, but it is not working. A connection to the database is made just fine....

While this code is not necessarily the most beautiful, it seems to me that it should work.

However, the trouble starts already at `if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql))`, whose conditions are not met for some reason?

```
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, redirect to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: add-event.php");
    exit;
    }

require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
    // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

    // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

    // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                        // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                        // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                        // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                        // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

    // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

// Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

The required variables are sent from a typical login form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
<div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">

    <H2>Username:</H2>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
    <H2>Password:</H2>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" style="width:80px;height:42px;font-size:18px;">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Because you aren't doing anything if the username and password is empty. You only have `if` no `else`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too.... but if a username and password are given, it should still work, no?

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)  and use them instead of subheadings.

Comment: How can you tell it stops after `if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){`? Have you added logging statements to check? Have you added an `else` to see if it would branch? Why are you trying to validate by testing the error variables you just assigned empty strings to anyway?

Comment: I was using `else {
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            } ` after each `if`, as well as adding echoes as the first line of each `if` statement to debug....

Comment: For one thing, it appears that the `if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql))` conditions are not met, which is confusing me....

Comment: @Quentin I learned to love labels long ago. As I mentioned, this code is take from an online demo/tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the worst login examples I have seen, if you want to learn how to set up a safe login easy to understand and easy to change look at this lesson.

https://clevertechie.com/php/20/login-system-php-mysql-database

Comment: Yes, I tend to agree with you. At a glance, I thought that the code might be salvageable, but I am inclined to give up on it....